# How to call two different mutation on same component in react with apollo?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-apollo

I am trying to call two different mutations on the different elements but it is not working. When I am calling the same mutation on the different element then it is working fine. I am calling TODO_OPERATIONS mutation on the start button and STOP_TIMER mutation on stop button then it is not working but when I am using TODO_OPERATIONS mutation on both action then it working fine. This is my code.

```
import { Mutation, Query } from "react-apollo";
import gql from "graphql-tag";
const React = require("react");
const ms = require("pretty-ms");
import ls from "local-storage";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import IconButton from "@material-ui/core/IconButton";
import Fab from "@material-ui/core/Fab";
import AddIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Add";
import Icon from "@material-ui/core/Icon";
import DeleteIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Delete";
import startIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Airplay";
import StartIcon from "@material-ui/icons/PlayCircleFilled";
import StopIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Stop";

const TODO_OPERATIONS = gql`
  mutation todo_operations(
    $id: String
    $status: String
    $dtask_start_time: String
    $time_tracking_flag: String
    $developer_daily_hours: String
    $is_task_started: String
    $actual_start_date: String
  ) {
    todo_operations(
      id: $id
      status: $status
      dtask_start_time: $dtask_start_time
      time_tracking_flag: $time_tracking_flag
      developer_daily_hours: $developer_daily_hours
      is_task_started: $is_task_started
      actual_start_date: $actual_start_date
    ) {
      id
    }
  }
`;

const STOP_TIMER = gql`
  mutation todo_operations(
    $id: String
    $dtask_stop_time: String
    $dtask_total_time: String
    $time_tracking_flag: String
  ) {
    todo_operations(
      id: $id
      dtask_stop_time: $dtask_start_time
      dtask_total_time: $dtask_total_time
      time_tracking_flag: $time_tracking_flag
    ) {
      id
    }
  }
`;

const styles = theme => ({
  button: {
    margin: theme.spacing.unit
  },
  input: {
    display: "none"
  }
});

class TaskTimer extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    let statetime = 0.0;
    let stateison = false;
    let statestart = 0;

    super(props);

    if (ls.get("startDatetime")) {
      if (ls.get("isOn") && ls.get("isOn") == 1) {
        stateison = true;
      }
      if (ls.get("stopDatetime")) {
        if (ls.get("isOn") && ls.get("isOn") == 1) {
          //Resume and then reloading page
          statestart = ls.get("startDatetime");
          statetime = Date.now() - statestart;
        } else {
          //Press stop and then reload page
          statetime = ls.get("time");
        }
      } else {
        //Reload page before stop clicked
        statestart = ls.get("startDatetime");
        statetime = Date.now() - statestart;
      }

      this.state = {
        time: statetime,
        isOn: stateison,
        start: statestart
      };
      if (ls.get("isOn") && ls.get("isOn") == 1) {
        this.startTimer();
      }
    }

    this.state = {
      time: statetime,
      isOn: stateison,
      start: statestart
    };

    this.startTimer = this.startTimer.bind(this);
    this.stopTimer = this.stopTimer.bind(this);
  }

  startTimer() {
    if (!ls.get("startDatetime")) ls.set("startDatetime", Date.now());
    ls.set("isOn", 1);
    ls.set("time", this.state.time);
    ls.set("start", Date.now() - this.state.time);

    this.setState({
      isOn: true,
      time: this.state.time,
      start: Date.now() - this.state.time
    });
    this.timer = setInterval(
      () =>
        this.setState({
          time: Date.now() - this.state.start
        }),
      1
    );
  }
  stopTimer() {
    ls.set("stopDatetime", Date.now());
    ls.set("isOn", 0);
    ls.set("time", this.state.time);

    this.setState({ isOn: false });
    clearInterval(this.timer);
  }

  render() {
    const { classes, theme } = this.props;

    let start =
      this.state.time == 0 ? (
        <Mutation mutation={TODO_OPERATIONS}>
          {(todo_operations, { loading, error }) => (
            <StartIcon
              variant="contained"
              color="primary"
              className={classes.button}
              onClick={event => {
                this.startTimer();
                todo_operations({
                  variables: {
                    id: "74eb7aa9-d996-c125-039d-5c7f6ad393b6",
                    status: "In Progress",
                    dtask_start_time: "2019-03-29 06:27:51",
                    time_tracking_flag: "No",
                    developer_daily_hours: "00",
                    is_task_started: "No",
                    actual_start_date: "2019-03-29 06:27:51"
                  }
                });
              }}
            />
          )}
        </Mutation>
      ) : null;

    let stop =
      this.state.time == 0 || !this.state.isOn ? null : (
        <Mutation mutation={STOP_TIMER}>
          {(todo_operations, { loading, error }) => (
            <StopIcon
              variant="contained"
              color="secondary"
              className={classes.button}
              onClick={event => {
                this.stopTimer();
                todo_operations({
                  variables: {
                    id: "74eb7aa9-d996-c125-039d-5c7f6ad393b6",
                    dtask_stop_time: "2019-03-29 06:27:51",
                    dtask_total_time: "2.00",
                    time_tracking_flag: "stop"
                  }
                });
              }}
            />
          )}
        </Mutation>
      );
    let resume =
      this.state.time == 0 || this.state.isOn ? null : (
        <StartIcon
          variant="contained"
          color="primary"
          className={classes.button}
          onClick={this.startTimer}
        />
      );

    return (
      <div>
        <h2>{ms(this.state.time)}</h2>
        {start}
        {resume}
        {stop}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withStyles(styles, { withTheme: true })(TaskTimer);
```

Anyone, please suggest me a solution.
Thanks.

Comment: Please describe what unexpected behavior you're seeing and not just say "it's not working". Are you seeing any errors? What behavior are you not seeing that you expected to see?

Comment: I am calling two mutations on the same page but only one mutation working another mutation not working.

Comment: Please specify which of the two mutations is the one that's not working. Check your console and verify that no errors are shown. You can also check the network tab and see if the mutation is being fired at all. All this information is helpful when debugging this sort of issue.